# Get a specific value from a function in R

Tags: r

I have this question, and sorry, i know it may be a dumb question but i don't know how to do it. I'm trying to understand a code in R.

I have 6 different scripts, each a function and then i save some outputs and work with those outputs.

There is this value, a vector, named:

```
u_cp
Something like: return(u_cp)
```

At the end of each function they do this:

```
return(output)
```

How do i retrieve then the u_cp value?

Ho do i return this value in one function and use it then?

Comment: You can use `list(u_cp = u_cp)` at the end of the function and the `$` to access it when calling, like `foo(x)$u_cp` There are variations on this.

Comment: You need to call the function. Whatever is specified inside `return()` is what the function gives back after it is evaluated. To use that object you should save it as a named object.

Comment: Maybe using a list? `return(list(u_cp, output))`?

Comment: So, how would i access it from your code? From here? return(list(u_cp, output))
How to access each one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if it's a function then the last expression is returned (in fact, the `return` statement is unnecessary there). What you would do is, you have a function `f`, which takes an input, say `x` and you call it and assign the value (if you wish to store it somehow) to a variable or pass it on to the rest of your  computation. Below an example of both

```
> f<-function(x) x+2
> r<-f(2)
> r
[1] 4
> f(2)+4
[1] 8
```